# ValidateRequest(false) not working with FormCollection

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have tried to add a reference to `System.Web.WebPages` DLL, and  `System.Web.Mvc`.
But its showing the following error:

The type `'System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder'` exists in both `'System.Web.Mvc.dll'` and `'System.Web.WebPages.dll'`.

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC 2.
How do I solve it?

Comment: Why do you need add reference to WebPages?

Answer (score 1):

System.Web.WebPages is not part of MVC2. Its part of MVC3.

In MVC3 Tagbuilder was moved from Mvc.dll to WebPages.dll. 
Thats why you get this error when you reference WebPages.dll in mvc2 projects.

Comment: My project is runing on .net framework 4.0 and I am using mvc2. The project cannot be upgraded to MVC 3 at the moment.
Alread I have used "Tagbuilder" at different place of my code.
Now I need to use "Form.Unvalidated()"

I have tried to add a reference to System.Web.WebPages DLL for Unvalidated(). But its showing the following error:
The type 'System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder' exists in both 'System.Web.Mvc.dll' and 'System.Web.WebPages.dll'
How I can solve it?

Comment: Like i wrote. You cant use WebPages.Dll in MVC2 projects, because it's Part of MVC3 and includes TagBuilder (former in MVC2.DLL)